# How to add underline text in docx4j?

Tags: docx4j

I am unable to find a way to insert underline text using docx4j. The code is given below.

```
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    P p = factory.createP();
    R r =  factory.createR();
    Text t = factory.createText();
    t.setValue("Test");
    r.getContent().add(t);
    p.getContent().add(r);
    RPr rpr = factory.createRPr();
    U u = factory.createU();
    rpr.setU(u);
    r.setRPr(rpr)
    mainDocumentPart.getContent().add(p);
    File exportFile = new File("welcome.docx");
    wordPackage.save(exportFile);
```

Comment: You are missing r.setRPr(rpr)

Comment: I already tried that but still not able to get underline text.

Comment: What does XmlUtils.marshaltoString(p) output?

Comment: <w:p>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:u/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Test</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are missing

> u.setVal(UnderlineEnumeration.SINGLE);

in your code.

Kindly try this code snippet

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
P p = factory.createP();
R r =  factory.createR();
Text t = factory.createText();
t.setValue("Test");
r.getContent().add(t);
p.getContent().add(r);
RPr rpr = factory.createRPr();
U u = factory.createU();
//This line here will do the trick for you.
u.setVal(UnderlineEnumeration.SINGLE);
rpr.setU(u);
r.setRPr(rpr)
mainDocumentPart.getContent().add(p);
File exportFile = new File("welcome.docx");
wordPackage.save(exportFile);
```